# JavaScript different webpages loading in same container

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a site where when I click on Grade 1, Grade 2 etc which are buttons it loads a page in my div "result". That is different website content is loaded each time I click on the button on the same page or inside the div container "result". My code is below. I was trying to use jQuery but I am new to this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#target").click(function(e) {
                    $('#result').load('http://www.youtube.com/user/EduGrade1');
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Grade.html"> CBSE Grades (1 to 12)</a>

                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href "http://www.youtube.com/user/EduGrade1" id="target"> Grade 1 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "http://www.youtube.com/user/EduGrade2"> Grade 2 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "#"> Grade 3 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "#"> Grade 4 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "#"> Grade 5 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "#"> Grade 6 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "#"> Grade 7 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "#"> Grade 8 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "#"> Grade 9 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "#"> Grade 10 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "#"> Grade 11 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href "http://www.youtube.com/user/EduGrade12"> Grade 12 </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <div id="div2">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>&nbsp; </p>
                <div id="result">
                    <script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&up_channel=EduGrade12&synd=open&w=480&h=340&title=&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js"></script>
                </div>
                </body>
```

Comment: jquery.load() cant load contents from different domain...!

Comment: And your problem is...?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".target").click(function(e) {
            var url = $(this).attr("link");
            $('#result').load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
                  if (status == "error") {
                        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                        $("#result").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                  }
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML Code, *but please be aware the pages need to be on same domain, you can not load cross domain using this approach, for opening cross domain pages you can use iframe instead.*

```
 <ul id="menu">
            <li class="target" style="cursor:pointer" link="page1.html">
                    Grade 1 </li>
            <li class="target" style="cursor:pointer" link="page2.html">
                    Grade 2 </li>       
        </ul>   
        <div id="result" style="width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid #000;"></div>
```

Below is a code snippet using Iframe

Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".target").click(function(e) {
            var url = $(this).attr("link");
            $('#resultFrame').attr("src",url);
        });
    });
```

Html Part

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li class="target" style="cursor:pointer" link="http://www.iotasol.com">
                Grade 1 </li>       
    </ul>   
    <div id="result" style="width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid #000;"><iframe id="resultFrame" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe></div>
```